# SQL Server searching a column of text for an exact phrase

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server and I am trying to figure out how to search through a column `tags` in my dbo.tickets and search for a phrase such as `lwr_tickets`.

Right now I have a query that will grab all the users tickets by date  and display there name. I am trying to figure out how to see what tickets were at what branch.

So the total number of tickets that were at `lwr_tickets`. The `tags` fieldname in the database has a long list of tag names separated by commas for each ticket. So I am trying to figure out how to write something that goes through the tag column and returns back just the ones that had `lwr_tickets` in it to get the total of that branch.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This find all tickets:

```
select
    u.Id,
    u.Name,
    t.submitter_id,
    COUNT(*) as numberOfTickets
from Users as u 
join Tickets as t on t.submitter_id = u.Id and t.created_at between '2017/11/01' and '2018/08/23'
group by u.Id, u.Name, t.submitter_id
```

Now trying to add the where that will search for `lwr_tickets`

Tried:

```
select
    u.Id,
    u.Name,
    t.submitter_id,
    COUNT(*) as numberOfTickets
from Users as u 
join Tickets as t on t.submitter_id = u.Id and t.created_at between '2017/11/01' and '2018/08/23'
group by u.Id, u.Name, t.submitter_id 
where t.tags = "lwr_tickets"
```

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE` goes after `FROM` and before `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Yep, you added the `WHERE` in the wrong place. Place it before the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Comma-delimited lists should *not* be stored in strings.  That is not how relational databases should be working.  There are lots of reasons.  Your data should have a `ticketTags` table with one row per ticket and per tag.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other peoples really, really, really, really bad design decisions.  You can use `like` for this:

```
select u.Id, u.Name, t.submitter_id,
       count(*) as numberOfTickets
from Users u join
     Tickets t
     on t.submitter_id = u.Id 
where t.created_at between '2017-11-01' and '2018-08-23' and
      ',' + t.tags + ',' like '%,' + 'lwr_tickets' + ',%'
group by u.Id, u.Name, t.submitter_id;
```

Notes:

- `where` goes after `from` and before `group by`.
- Strings are delimited by single quotes in SQL in general (and in SQL Server in particular).
- The hyphen is (ISO) standard for dates, which is why I use it.
- There is little you can do to improve performance.